# Running GLMs by group and then printing the output?

Tags: r, model, glm, lme4

I am trying to do generalised linear models on different groups within a bigger dataset. So, I have a dataset that is split by populations and I want to do the same glm on the different populations and then print the output.

I have managed to do this for a linear model with the code:

```
powerana7 <- data_sim6 %>% 
  nest(data = -squid_pop) %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(y~ early_diet_group + 
                                 later_diet_group + 
                                 early_diet_group*later_diet_group + 
                                 age + 
                                 SVL + 
                                 egg_batch + 
                                 individual, 
                               data = .)), 
         tidied = map(model, tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(tidied)
```

here,

```
data_sim6 = my dataset
```

and the factors within the lm are components of the dataset.

But I cannot work out how to do the same thing with a glm, does anyone know?

Comment: What's the `glm` you want to run? What did you try? What was the result?

Comment: Also, do you want to run a mixed effects model from the `lme4` package? If so, please describe it. If not, remove the `lme4` tag from your question.

Comment: Hi, yes. I tried running the same code with lmer from lme4                                                 powerana2 <- data_sim %>% 
  nest(data = -squid_pop) %>%
  mutate(model = map(data,lmer(y ~ age + early_diet_group + later_diet_group + (1|age/individual), data = data_sim_model), data = .)), tidied = map(model, tidy))  %>%
  unnest(tidied)                                                                                                                     It comes up with an error about unexpected charcters

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that produced the error and also show the actual error--the error messages are often very informative. I will say that, at a glance, `data = data_sim_model), data = .)` looks wrong. You should only be specifying the data one time. Make sure your parentheses line up and there aren't any extras.